# Insert R code in Latex

Tags: r

How can I define the color for the \listings package to display R code in Latex to get the result exactly like in the R Studio platform (example like in the figure)? [image]

Comment: The `listings` manual describes how to set the style for various things like keywords and comments. You'll need to play with the various options until you get the color scheme you want. If there's something particularly tricky, you should ask about that specifically.

Comment: I'm not a user of R, but you may be able to look up the colours used within R from the settings panel, as if you were to set up a new style.

Comment: @TH Do you have the code for defining the code color like in the figure?

Comment: I really dislike `listings`. Have you considered using `minted` for this - I believe Pygments (which is *actually* purpose built for syntax highlighting code) does support R? You could presumably define your own colour scheme if necessary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not going to find every possible case of how R studio styles code. But maybe this will get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#Calculate CE for each counterparty
Value.A <- data.frame() #MTM value of each contract within cp A
# ...
for(i in 1:length(foo)){
  if(isTrue(as.character(portfolio_data[i,1])=="A")==TRUE){
    # ...
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It may be easier to simply define a new language (or variant) that contains exactly what you want based off of `listings`'s definition which is in lstlang3.sty. The definition for R is this.

```
\lst@definelanguage{R}%
  {keywords={abbreviate,abline,abs,acos,acosh,action,add1,add,%
      aggregate,alias,Alias,alist,all,anova,any,aov,aperm,append,apply,%
      approx,approxfun,apropos,Arg,args,array,arrows,as,asin,asinh,%
      atan,atan2,atanh,attach,attr,attributes,autoload,autoloader,ave,%
      axis,backsolve,barplot,basename,besselI,besselJ,besselK,besselY,%
      beta,binomial,body,box,boxplot,break,browser,bug,builtins,bxp,by,%
      c,C,call,Call,case,cat,category,cbind,ceiling,character,char,%
      charmatch,check,chol,chol2inv,choose,chull,class,close,cm,codes,%
      coef,coefficients,co,col,colnames,colors,colours,commandArgs,%
      comment,complete,complex,conflicts,Conj,contents,contour,%
      contrasts,contr,control,helmert,contrib,convolve,cooks,coords,%
      distance,coplot,cor,cos,cosh,count,fields,cov,covratio,wt,CRAN,%
      create,crossprod,cummax,cummin,cumprod,cumsum,curve,cut,cycle,D,%
      data,dataentry,date,dbeta,dbinom,dcauchy,dchisq,de,debug,%
      debugger,Defunct,default,delay,delete,deltat,demo,de,density,%
      deparse,dependencies,Deprecated,deriv,description,detach,%
      dev2bitmap,dev,cur,deviance,off,prev,,dexp,df,dfbetas,dffits,%
      dgamma,dgeom,dget,dhyper,diag,diff,digamma,dim,dimnames,dir,%
      dirname,dlnorm,dlogis,dnbinom,dnchisq,dnorm,do,dotplot,double,%
      download,dpois,dput,drop,drop1,dsignrank,dt,dummy,dump,dunif,%
      duplicated,dweibull,dwilcox,dyn,edit,eff,effects,eigen,else,%
      emacs,end,environment,env,erase,eval,equal,evalq,example,exists,%
      exit,exp,expand,expression,External,extract,extractAIC,factor,%
      fail,family,fft,file,filled,find,fitted,fivenum,fix,floor,for,%
      For,formals,format,formatC,formula,Fortran,forwardsolve,frame,%
      frequency,ftable,ftable2table,function,gamma,Gamma,gammaCody,%
      gaussian,gc,gcinfo,gctorture,get,getenv,geterrmessage,getOption,%
      getwd,gl,glm,globalenv,gnome,GNOME,graphics,gray,grep,grey,grid,%
      gsub,hasTsp,hat,heat,help,hist,home,hsv,httpclient,I,identify,if,%
      ifelse,Im,image,\%in\%,index,influence,measures,inherits,install,%
      installed,integer,interaction,interactive,Internal,intersect,%
      inverse,invisible,IQR,is,jitter,kappa,kronecker,labels,lapply,%
      layout,lbeta,lchoose,lcm,legend,length,levels,lgamma,library,%
      licence,license,lines,list,lm,load,local,locator,log,log10,log1p,%
      log2,logical,loglin,lower,lowess,ls,lsfit,lsf,ls,machine,Machine,%
      mad,mahalanobis,make,link,margin,match,Math,matlines,mat,matplot,%
      matpoints,matrix,max,mean,median,memory,menu,merge,methods,min,%
      missing,Mod,mode,model,response,mosaicplot,mtext,mvfft,na,nan,%
      names,omit,nargs,nchar,ncol,NCOL,new,next,NextMethod,nextn,%
      nlevels,nlm,noquote,NotYetImplemented,NotYetUsed,nrow,NROW,null,%
      numeric,\%o\%,objects,offset,old,on,Ops,optim,optimise,optimize,%
      options,or,order,ordered,outer,package,packages,page,pairlist,%
      pairs,palette,panel,par,parent,parse,paste,path,pbeta,pbinom,%
      pcauchy,pchisq,pentagamma,persp,pexp,pf,pgamma,pgeom,phyper,pico,%
      pictex,piechart,Platform,plnorm,plogis,plot,pmatch,pmax,pmin,%
      pnbinom,pnchisq,pnorm,points,poisson,poly,polygon,polyroot,pos,%
      postscript,power,ppoints,ppois,predict,preplot,pretty,Primitive,%
      print,prmatrix,proc,prod,profile,proj,prompt,prop,provide,%
      psignrank,ps,pt,ptukey,punif,pweibull,pwilcox,q,qbeta,qbinom,%
      qcauchy,qchisq,qexp,qf,qgamma,qgeom,qhyper,qlnorm,qlogis,qnbinom,%
      qnchisq,qnorm,qpois,qqline,qqnorm,qqplot,qr,Q,qty,qy,qsignrank,%
      qt,qtukey,quantile,quasi,quit,qunif,quote,qweibull,qwilcox,%
      rainbow,range,rank,rbeta,rbind,rbinom,rcauchy,rchisq,Re,read,csv,%
      csv2,fwf,readline,socket,real,Recall,rect,reformulate,regexpr,%
      relevel,remove,rep,repeat,replace,replications,report,require,%
      resid,residuals,restart,return,rev,rexp,rf,rgamma,rgb,rgeom,R,%
      rhyper,rle,rlnorm,rlogis,rm,rnbinom,RNGkind,rnorm,round,row,%
      rownames,rowsum,rpois,rsignrank,rstandard,rstudent,rt,rug,runif,%
      rweibull,rwilcox,sample,sapply,save,scale,scan,scan,screen,sd,se,%
      search,searchpaths,segments,seq,sequence,setdiff,setequal,set,%
      setwd,show,sign,signif,sin,single,sinh,sink,solve,sort,source,%
      spline,splinefun,split,sqrt,stars,start,stat,stem,step,stop,%
      storage,strstrheight,stripplot,strsplit,structure,strwidth,sub,%
      subset,substitute,substr,substring,sum,summary,sunflowerplot,svd,%
      sweep,switch,symbol,symbols,symnum,sys,status,system,t,table,%
      tabulate,tan,tanh,tapply,tempfile,terms,terrain,tetragamma,text,%
      time,title,topo,trace,traceback,transform,tri,trigamma,trunc,try,%
      ts,tsp,typeof,unclass,undebug,undoc,union,unique,uniroot,unix,%
      unlink,unlist,unname,untrace,update,upper,url,UseMethod,var,%
      variable,vector,Version,vi,warning,warnings,weighted,weights,%
      which,while,window,write,\%x\%,x11,X11,xedit,xemacs,xinch,xor,%
      xpdrows,xy,xyinch,yinch,zapsmall,zip},%
   otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},%
   alsoother={._$},%
   sensitive,%
   morecomment=[l]\#,%
   morestring=[d]",%
   morestring=[d]'% 2001 Robert Denham
  }%
```

I suspect you don't want most of those keywords.

Comment: Why the system informs the error: Option clash for package color

Comment: @Duy, presumably some other package has used `\RequirePackage{color}` which is causing a conflict. Without the code you're using that causes an error, I'm not sure precisely. One possibility is to provide any necessary `xcolor` package options to the `\documentclass`.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}`

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to include code of any programming language into LaTeX.

***Just verbatim***

```
    \begin{verbatim}
    # Creating a Graph
    attach(mtcars)
    plot(wt, mpg)
    abline(lm(mpg~wt))
    title("Regression of MPG on Weight")
    \end{verbatim}
```

[image]

***Custom listing***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true, numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt, showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false, showtabs=false, tabsize=2}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
# Creating a Graph
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg)
abline(lm(mpg~wt))
title("Regression of MPG on Weight")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Minted package (beautiful Highlighting)***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{R}
# Creating a Graph
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg)
abline(lm(mpg~wt))
title("Regression of MPG on Weight")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

***or choose colour styles for minted***

add `\usemintedstyle{monokai}` in preambula

[image]

1. [minted source](https://ru.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted)
2. [code listing source](https://ru.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing)