# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Darkgreen'

Tags: errors

I'm trying to copy a latex R code, but it happens that I have the following error and I don't know how to fix it:

`` !  Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Darkgreen'. ``

I tried also with
`\ usepackage [svgnames] {xcolor}`,

and got the error:

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`

I used this answer to put my code from R to latex: [Insert R code in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374001/insert-r-code-in-latex)

How is it fixed and why is it undefined? Sorry if the code is not minimally reproducible, but I tried to put it in the best way so that it is understood

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[figurename=Figura]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Code example
#Comment code example
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it may help if you explain where you copied the code from(for example if it's from some answer we can also edit the answer or something)

Comment: "Sorry if the code is not minimally reproducible" Why not make it reproducible then? At least add the documentclass line.

Comment: [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) only offers `DarkGreen`, not `Darkgreen`, under `svgnames`.

Comment: I also tried and it gives me error. I just edited my post where that appears. I cannot put all the code because it is a scientific article that I am going to publish, I try to put the part of my error with as much context as possible

Comment: So your "updated" code still uses `Darkgreen`, not `DarkGreen`.

Comment: Sorry. I had corrected it in my code, but he forgot to put it here

Comment: "I cannot put all the code because it is a scientific article that I am going to publish" That's exactly why you should make a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for guidelines.

Comment: For the latter case it's caused by something else in your preamble and you need a MWE. But also see [pgfplots - Option clash for package xcolor - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor?rq=1) for ways to fix it locally.

Comment: we do not need _any_ of the words from your article, but the code posted should be _an example of the problem_ otherwise the code is no use helping anyone help you. Clearly you have defined `DarkGreen` (from `svgnames`) but used `Darkgreen` so get an error, but the code you have posted does not do that so it is unrelated to your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For the option clash, it is quite  possible  that  some other package loads xcolor without this option or with another option. A solution, if this is indeed the case, would be to load the `svgnames` option as an option for `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 4):

*Before* `\documentclass` use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{...}
```

or simply use

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
```

And then, as already mentioned, use `DarkGreen`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I ended up using my own definition for "DarkGreen"

```
\definecolor{DarkGreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
```

Add this command before `\begin{document}`.  To play with how "DarkGreen" looks you can change the numbers 1,50, 32.  This determines how much red/green/blue there is to create the color.  I got this color by literally googling "DarkGreen rgb".  [https://encycolorpedia.com/013220#:~:text=The%20color%20dark%20green%20with,%25%20green%20and%2012.55%25%20blue](https://encycolorpedia.com/013220#:%7E:text=The%20color%20dark%20green%20with,%25%20green%20and%2012.55%25%20blue).