# Add R code to Latex document

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, r

I have a small amount of code I wrote in RStudio that my supervisors want me to include. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to include R code as part of a larger Latex document?

Comment: Can this be of any help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374007/245337